# the out put of code doesn't change after change in code

Tags: html, reactjs

I started learning react by writhing this simple code. but it shows me different output in the browser I mean my previous example. I refresh it many times but noting has changed. I write code in visual studio code.
I write this code as App.js

```
 import React from 'react';

 class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
     header: "Header from state...",
     content: "Content from state..."
  }
}
render() {
   return (
      <div>
         <h1>{this.state.header}</h1>
        <h2>{this.state.content}</h2>
     </div>
   );
}
}
export default App;
```

and this as main.js

```
 import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
This will produce the following result.
```

this as index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">

      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>React App</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id = "app">

      </div>
      <script src="build/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What environment are you developing in? Create React App? Are you using a custom Webpack configuration?

Comment: visual studio code

Comment: How is your project set up? Did you use `create-react-app` to create the project and `npm start` to run the dev server?

Comment: i use this in cmd: gulp watch